# Google App Engine based Node Js server does not work on Reliance Jio network in India

Tags: domain-name-system, firewall, google-cloud-platform, node.js, google-app-engine

Requests to my node server deployed on GAE ends in *DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN* on a particular ISP (Reliance JIO in India). The same app works fine on any other network . If deployed on Heroku or on AWS, again it works as expected.

Edit: Forgot to mention, I have tried all devices, iOS, Android, Mac and Win, zeroed down on this ISP. All other combinations work (i.e any other ISP and any other device and any browser).

The combination of Reliance Jio's network and Google Cloud (Google App Engine) does not work.

What to do here? What could be the issue? Is there something on my end that I have not configured?

Comment: Please don't repost questions. If your original post didn't get an answer, you should [improve it](/help/no-one-answers) instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node server returns DNS\_PROBE\_FINISHED\_NXDOMAIN on a particular service provider](https://serverfault.com/questions/1046922/node-server-returns-dns-probe-finished-nxdomain-on-a-particular-service-provider)

Comment: Sorry Michael, unintentionally reposted. @DaveM that is my question only. Have deleted that now.